# Awaiting multiple aiohttp requests cause 'Session is closed' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, aiohttp

I am writing a helper class for handling multiple urls request in asynchronous way. The code is following.

```
class urlAsyncClient(object):
    def  __init__(self, url_arr):
        self.url_arr = url_arr

    async def async_worker(self):
        result = await self.__run()
        return result

    async def __run(self):
        pending_req = []
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            for url in self.url_arr:
                r = self.__fetch(session, url)
                pending_req.append(r)
        #Awaiting the results altogether instead of one by one
        result = await asyncio.wait(pending_req)
        return result

    @staticmethod
    async def __fetch(session, url):
        async with session.get(url) as response: #ERROR here
            status_code = response.status
            if status_code == 200:
                return await response.json()
            else:
                result = await response.text()
                print('Error ' + str(response.status_code) + ': ' + result)
                return {"error": result}
```

As awaiting the result one by one seems meaningless in asynchronous. I put them into an array and wait together by `await asyncio.wait(pending_req)`.

But seems like it is not the correct way to do it as I get the following error

> in __fetch async with session.get(url) as response: RuntimeError: Session is closed

May I know the correct way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because session has closed before you await it

```
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in self.url_arr:
            r = self.__fetch(session, url)
            pending_req.append(r)
  #session closed hear
```

you can make session an argument to `__run`, like this

```
async def async_worker(self):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        result = await self.__run(session)
        return result
    # session will close hear

async def __run(self, session):
    pending_req = []
    for url in self.url_arr:
        r = self.__fetch(session, url)
        pending_req.append(r)
    #Awaiting the results altogether instead of one by one
    result = await asyncio.wait(pending_req)
    return result
```